# Gridview user-controls cant get row data

Tags: asp.net, .net, gridview, webforms, user-controls

This is my .ascx file:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None" Width="905px" 
OnRowDataBound="OnRowDataBound" OnRowEditing="GridView1_RowEditing" style="margin-right: 4px" >
<AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
<Columns>
    <asp:CheckBoxField DataField="IsChecked" HeaderText="" SortExpression="IsChecked" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="Description" HeaderText="Benefit"  ><ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" /></asp:BoundField>

    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Description">
    <ItemTemplate>
    <asp:TextBox runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Detail") %>' Width="70px" ID="Description"  OnTextChanged="DescriptionTextChanged" />
    </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField> 

    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Ammount">
    <ItemTemplate>
    <asp:TextBox runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Ammount") %>' Width="50px" ID="Ammount"  />
    </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField> 

    <asp:CheckBoxField DataField="Optional" HeaderText="Optional" SortExpression="Optional" />

    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Copayment">
    <ItemTemplate>
    <asp:TextBox runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Copayment") %>' Width="40px" ID="Copayment" />
    </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>

    <asp:CheckBoxField DataField="Complementary" HeaderText="Complementary" SortExpression="Complementary" />
    <asp:CheckBoxField DataField="Covered" HeaderText="Covered" SortExpression="Covered" />
</Columns>
```

This is the save button.

```
<asp:Button ID="myButton" Text="Save" OnClick="Save_OnClick" runat="server" />
```

Total of 8 fields. And here is the C# code.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
     ... //get data etc etc
         GridView1.DataSource = myResults;
         GridView1.DataBind();
    }
```

By default all my fields on the grid were disabled, so I did this to enable the fields I needed:

```
    protected void OnRowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            CheckBox checkBox = e.Row.Cells[0].Controls[0] as CheckBox;
            checkBox.Enabled = true;

            checkBox = e.Row.Cells[4].Controls[0] as CheckBox;
            checkBox.Enabled = true;

            checkBox = e.Row.Cells[6].Controls[0] as CheckBox;
            checkBox.Enabled = true;

            checkBox = e.Row.Cells[7].Controls[0] as CheckBox;
            checkBox.Enabled = true;
        }
    }
```

Here is the button event that loops through the GridView and collects the info.

```
    public void Save_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView1.Rows)
        {
            CheckBox chk = row.Cells[0].Controls[0] as CheckBox;
            bool isChecked = chk.Checked;
            string benefit = row.Cells[1].Text;
            string description = ((TextBox)row.FindControl("Description")).Text;
            string ammount = ((TextBox)row.FindControl("Ammount")).Text;
            chk = row.Cells[4].Controls[0] as CheckBox;
            bool optional = chk.Checked;
            string copayment = ((TextBox)row.FindControl("Copayment")).Text;
            chk = row.Cells[6].Controls[0] as CheckBox;
            bool complementary = chk.Checked; 
            chk = row.Cells[7].Controls[0] as CheckBox;
            bool covered = chk.Checked; 
        }
    }
```

Table is loaded correctly from the entities and the checkboxes become available as the entities say.

**The problem** is that when editing the GridView like enabling/disabling checkboxes or changing text on textfields these values wont get saved when I press the "Save" button. They are the same values as when the table loaded.

**My guess** is that there isnt any "update" event, but I tried adding 'OnRowEditing' to the gridview but it never fires...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the issue is in your page load event. You need to bind data as below

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(!IsPostBack)
    { 
         GridView1.DataSource = myResults;
         GridView1.DataBind();
     }
}
```

because when you click button the get loaded automatically and the edited values it overwritten.

Create a method to bind data in gridview and call it where ever it is required. 
Like

```
public void BindDatatoGrid
{
    ... //get data etc etc
     GridView1.DataSource = myResults;
     GridView1.DataBind();
}
```

and use this function

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(!IsPostBack)
    { 
         BindDatatoGrid();
     }
}
```